# Background service running but not functioning properly in kitkat devices

Tags: android, android-service, android-4.4-kitkat

### What I have

A background service that changes the wallpaper of a device automatically from a few selected images. It runs perfectly fine on lolipop and post lolipop devices. But the problem arises when I try it on a kitkat device. The service stays alive but doesn't function as I can't see the wallpapers changing.

### How do I know the service is alive?

On a kitkat device, when I go to Settings->Apps->Running. It shows 1 service running for my app and since it is the only service I have implemented in the whole app, I am sure that the service is alive. Moreover, **greenify** shows that the service is still running.

### What the service is supposed to do

Users can download images which get stored in a specific folder. When the user sets the interval after which the wallpaper should change and clicks on a button to start it, the background service is started which derives the bitmap from those previously downloaded images and sets them as wallpaper after specified intervals.

### The manifest declaration for the service

```
<service android:name=".AutomaticWallpaperChanger" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
```

### Code for the service:

```
public class AutomaticWallpaperChanger  extends Service {
// constant
public static long NOTIFY_INTERVAL;
Boolean shuffle;
int wallpaper;
SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

// run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
// timer handling
private Timer mTimer = null;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("onstart gallery dialog","called");
    editor.putBoolean("service not running",false).commit();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // cancel if already existed
    if (mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();
    } else {
        // recreate new
        mTimer = new Timer();
    }
    mySharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("preferences", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor= mySharedPreferences.edit();
    AutomaticWallpaperChanger.NOTIFY_INTERVAL=mySharedPreferences.getInt("interval",3600);//3600*1000)*1000;
    AutomaticWallpaperChanger.NOTIFY_INTERVAL*=1000;
    // schedule task
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
}



class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("timer","Running");
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        //"running",
                       // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // display toast
                AsyncTask asyncTask= new AsyncTask() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "WallR"+ File.separator + "Gallery");
                        if(folder.exists()) {
                            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                            shuffle = mySharedPreferences.getBoolean("checked", false);
                            Log.d("shuffle", String.valueOf(shuffle));
                            if (shuffle != true) {

                                if (listOfFiles.length != 0) {
                                    wallpaper = mySharedPreferences.getInt("wallpaper", 0);
                                    wallpaper++;
                                    editor.putInt("wallpaper", wallpaper);
                                    editor.commit();
                                    if (wallpaper >= listOfFiles.length) {
                                        wallpaper = 0;
                                        editor.putInt("wallpaper", wallpaper);
                                        editor.commit();
                                    }
                                    Log.d("wallpaperr number", String.valueOf(wallpaper));
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listOfFiles[wallpaper].getPath());
                                    WallpaperManager mWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                                    try {
                                        mWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    bitmap.recycle();
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                if (listOfFiles.length != 0) {
                                    wallpaper = mySharedPreferences.getInt("wallpaper", 0);
                                    wallpaper++;
                                    editor.putInt("wallpaper", wallpaper);
                                    editor.commit();
                                    if (wallpaper >= listOfFiles.length) {
                                        wallpaper = 0;
                                        editor.putInt("wallpaper", wallpaper);
                                        editor.commit();
                                    }
                                    shuffleArray(listOfFiles);
                                    Log.d("wallpaperr number", String.valueOf(wallpaper));
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listOfFiles[wallpaper].getPath());
                                    WallpaperManager mWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                                    try {
                                        mWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    bitmap.recycle();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                asyncTask.execute();

            }

        });
    }
    void shuffleArray(File[] ar)
    {
        // If running on Java 6 or older, use `new Random()` on RHS here
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            // Simple swap
            File a = ar[index];
            ar[index] = ar[i];
            ar[i] = a;
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
        editor.putBoolean("service not running", true).commit();
        mTimer.cancel();
        mTimer.purge();

}

}
```

### My observations

The service runs perfectly fine for lollipop, marshmallow and nougat devices. But for kitkat devices, it runs as long as the app is open. After I swipe the app out of the recent apps, the service stays alive but doesn't change the wallpaper anymore.

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I had same problem long ago, I think kitkat does kill the service, try to periodically show a Toast to see if your toast still appears after you swipe off it from menu?

Comment: I will surely try what you've suggested but as I have said, in the settings, it shows that the service is running.

Comment: Just a random thought, for this task wouldn't be more appropriate to use AlarmManager?

Comment: @lelloman, thanks for your suggestion. Alarm manager solves the current problem but another issue rises i,e if the interval is set to 10 minutes, but the device stays asleep for an hour, the next time that the device is unlocked, alarm manager keeps on firing the service 6 times continuously, since the device was on sleep and missed 6 of them. This continuous repetition of the service 6 times, results in the malfunctioning of the wallpaper manager and thus the wallpapers are not set properly. Any way to skip the calls, which were missed during the period when the phone was asleep?

Comment: hum, I think you can use alarm manager this way: set the time for the next alarm just the next one, no repeat, it should fire even if the device is locked. when the next alarm fires, check if the device is lock (don't change wallpaper) and set the next alarm. you will need to intercept also boot completed event to restore next alarm